# form_invalid method not displaying fields in error

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a CBV CreateView and a django form that behaves correctly when you entered data that is valid. However, when the form has fields in error (duplicate phone number or more than one primary contact phone), then is re-displayed by form_invalid method, but the fields that were previously populated are now displayed blank.

The customUser field in the Phone model which is the foreign key to the user CustomUser(AbstractUser) model appears to be blank when I print the request.post data.

This is my model:

```
class Phone(models.Model):

   COUNTRIES = (
       (55, _('Brazil')),
       (1, _('United States of America')),
   )
   PHONETYPES = (
       ('1', _('Mobile')),
       ('2', _('Home')),
       ('3', _('Work')),
       ('4', _('Other')),
   )
   status = models.CharField(_("Record Status"), max_length=1, default='A')
   status_dt = models.DateTimeField(_("Status Date"), default=timezone.now)
   customUser = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, verbose_name=_("User"), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

   phone_name = models.CharField(_("Phone name"), max_length=20, default="PH"+str(random.randint(1,99999)))

   country = models.IntegerField(_("Country Dialing Code"), choices=COUNTRIES)
   
   phone_number = models.CharField(_("Phone Number"), max_length=11)

   phone_type = models.CharField(_("Phone Type"), max_length=1, default="4", choices=PHONETYPES)

   verified = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('verified'), default=False)
   primary = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('primary'), default=False)

   at_user = models.CharField(_("Audit Trail (user)"), max_length=255, blank=True)
   at_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(_("Audit Trail (IP)"), protocol='both', blank=True, null=True)
   at_dttm = models.DateTimeField(_("Audit Trail (Date-Time)"), default=timezone.now)
   at_action = models.CharField(_("Audit Trail (Function performed)"), max_length=255, blank=True)
   UniqueConstraint(fields=['customUser', 'country', 'phone_number'], name='user_unique_phone_number')

   class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Phone Number")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Phone Numbers")
           
   @classmethod
   def create(cls, user):
       phone = cls(customUser = CustomUser.objects.get(id=user))
       # phone create
       return phone

   def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_name
```

This is my form:

```
class PhoneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
  class Meta:
    model = Phone
    
    fields = 'customUser', 'phone_name', 'country', 'phone_number', 'phone_type', 'primary'
    widgets = {'customUser': forms.HiddenInput()} 

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
       
        super(PhoneForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['customUser'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
        self.fields['primary'].help_text = _('<strong>Check:</strong> If this is your main contact phone number.')
   

  def clean(self):
        
        cleaned_data = super(PhoneForm, self).clean()
        
        customUser = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        phone_name = cleaned_data.get('phone_name')
        country = cleaned_data.get('country')
        phone_number = cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
        phone_type = cleaned_data.get('phone_type')
        primary = cleaned_data.get('primary')
                       
        if "action_add" in self.request.POST:
            
            try:
                phonenum = Phone.objects.filter(customUser=customUser, country=country, phone_number=phone_number).first()
                if phonenum:
                    #messages.error(self.request, _('This Phone is registered already.')) 
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_('This Phone is registered already.'), code='invalid')
            except Phone.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            
            try:
                phone = Phone.objects.filter(customUser=customUser, primary=True).first()
                if phone and primary:
                    
                    #messages.error(self.request, _('There is another "Primary" Phone already.'))
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_('There is another "Primary" Phone already.'), code='invalid')
                    
            except Phone.DoesNotExist:
                pass
            
        if "action_update" in self.request.POST:
          
          if "country" in self.changed_data or "phone_number" in self.changed_data:
                        
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('You can´t update the Country nor the Phone number of the existing Phone.'), code='invalid')
          try:
              phone = Phone.objects.filter(customUser=customUser, primary=True).first()
              if phone and primary and self.request.session['Phone_object_id'] != phone.id: 
                  
                  raise forms.ValidationError(_('There is another "Primary" Phone already.'), code='invalid')
                  
          except Phone.DoesNotExist:
              pass                  
        if not phone_name and not phone_type and not phone_number:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_('You have to fill out the form!'), code='invalid')
```

This is my view:

```
class PhoneCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = PhoneForm
    model = Phone
    template_name = 'phones/addPhone.html'
    login_url = reverse_lazy('account_login')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('phonesList')
     
    class Meta:
        readonly = ('customUser', )

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kw = super(PhoneCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kw['request'] = self.request  
        return kw
    
    def get_initial(self):
       
        phone = Phone.create(self.request.user.id)
        form = self.form_class(instance=phone)
        form.instance.customUser = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        
        return {'form': form, }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        form_class = PhoneForm
        context = super(PhoneCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = self.form_class(instance=self.object)
        context['customUser'] = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        context['form'] = form
        return context
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #request.POST['customUser'] = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        customUser = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        print('################ Request.POST: ', request.POST)
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        
        form.instance.customUser = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id) 
               
        form.instance.status = 'A' 
        form.instance.status_dt = timezone.now()
        form.instance.at_user = self.request.user.email
        form.instance.at_ip = visitor_ip_address(self.request) 
        form.instance.at_dttm = timezone.now()
        form.instance.at_action = 'Create Phone number'
        
        messages.success(self.request, _('Your Phone Number has been registered.'))
        return super(PhoneCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
        
        messages.error(self.request,  _('Your Phone record has errors.'))
        
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(request=self.request, form=form))
```

Comment: I have commented out the line "context['form'] = form"  in the view method get_context_data and now,  all the fields are shown in template.  However, I get an error saying that the  mandatory fields customUser is empty.  I am populating it so I don´t know why it is not taking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the method get_context_data in my view as follows:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #Use this to add extra context.#
        context = super(PhoneCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        form = self.form_class(instance=self.object)
        form.instance.customUser = CustomUser.objects.get(id=self.request.user.id)
        
        return context
```